# How to uninstall gitahead from ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, gitahead

I am not able to unistall gitahead from ubuntu. I need help regarding how to uninstall gitahead from ubuntu. I had downloaded the file from internet and had install using .sh file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you getting an error message? would be helpfull if you can give more details about the error.

When you download the **GitAhead-2.6.3.sh** file just allow executing file as a program in the permission tab when you right click on the file in your file manager.
Then jump into the CLI move to the directory where the file has downloaded normaly in `/home/userName/Downloads` and there list the files with `ls -l` command to make sure the file is there, here when you execute the script with `sudo ./GitAhead-2.6.3.sh` command it will create a new Directory with the name GitAhead, move into the new directory `cd GitAhead` and run again `ls -l` and you should see another GitAhead file this one is the one you want to execute to run the GUI just by typing `./GitAhead` it should start running.

To uninstall it if you dont want it any more you can just delete the GitAhead root directory, in your File Manager right click and then `Move to trash`, or the comand `rm -r /home/userName/Downloads/GitAhead`

Hope you find this helpful
Regards!

Comment: Make sure you also remove the desktop icon file. ~/.local/share/applications/gitahead.desktop.  Else it will keep coming up when you search with the quick menu.